# Affecting a function to another function in c++

Tags: c++

So there's this code am trying to understand:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x = -2;

int h(int &x) {
  x = 2 * x;
  return x;
}

int g(int f) { return x; }

int &f(int &x) {
  x += ::x;
  return x;
}

int main() {
  int x = 6;
  f(::x) = h(x);
  cout << f(x) << endl;
  cout << g(x) << endl;
  cout << h(x) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
24
12
48
```

I understood the function of the scope resolution operator (::), which is to use the global `int x`, but the part that i don't understand is this part: `f(::x) = h(x);` and this one: `int g(int f){return x;}`

So what am trying to understand is what happens step by step when these instructions get executed.

Comment: Which version of C++ are you using? I believe the rules have changed for this code (specifically whether in `f(::x) = h(x);` f or h is called first.

Comment: Functions `f(::x)` and `h(x)` are called and the return value of `h(x)` is assigned to the return value of `f(::x)`. The order of function calls is irrelevant because in `main` `x` and `::x` are two different variables and in `f` `x` is a reference to `::x`.

Comment: `int g(int f){return x;}` is easy to understand, it returns the value of the global `x` variable.

Comment: not quite clear where your not-understanding starts, `int &f(int &x)` takes a reference and returns a reference, do you know what that means?

Comment: I get it's a fun "puzzle," but this a prime time to recommend a debugger and actually observe how the program executes, step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
f(::x) = h(x);
```

is equivalent to

```
operator=(f(::x), h(x));
```

First, one of the functions `f` or `h` are called and the returned value is passed to `operator=`. Then the other function is called and the returned value is passed to `operator=`. The order is irrelevant because in either case `f` changes the value of global `x` to `-4` and returns a reference to it and `h` changes local `x` (local in `main`) to 12 and returns its value. Then the value 12 is assigned to global `x`.

The line

```
int g(int f) { return x; }
```

defines a function that returns the value of global `x`.

Maybe using different variable names helps understanding:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int globalX = -2;

int h(int &hX) {
  hX = 2 * hX;
  return hX;
}

int g(int f) { return globalX; } // f is unused

int &f(int &fX) {
  fX += ::globalX;
  return fX;
}

int main() {
  int mainX = 6;
  f(::globalX) = h(mainX);
  cout << f(mainX) << endl;
  cout << g(mainX) << endl;
  cout << h(mainX) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```